# Autoref and hyperref colors customization

Tags: cross-referencing, autoref

How to change the colour of cross-reference, I want the label to be in black and the number in blue as in the image [image: as in the image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    Insert cross reference \autoref{figure}
\begin{figure}%h!
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Validation procedure for LR model}\label{figure}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do three things:

1. Define your blue color.
2. Assign hyperref's `linkcolor`-key your defined blue color.
3. Patch `\HyRef@testreftype` to resort to the current textcolor before delivering the name/type of the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylinkcolor}{rgb}{0.561, 0.667, 0.863}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=mylinkcolor]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyAutoefPhrasecolorGroup[1]{%
  \color@begingroup\color{MyCurrentcolor}#1\endgroup
}%
\def\HyRef@testreftype#1.#2\\{%
 \colorlet{MyCurrentcolor}{.}%
 \ltx@IfUndefined{#1autorefname}{%
   \ltx@IfUndefined{#1name}{%
     \HyRef@StripStar#1\\*\\\@nil{#1}%
     \ltx@IfUndefined{\HyRef@name autorefname}{%
       \ltx@IfUndefined{\HyRef@name name}{%
         \def\HyRef@currentHtag{}%
         \Hy@Warning{No autoref name for `#1'}%
       }{%
         \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
           \noexpand\MyAutoefPhrasecolorGroup{%
             \expandafter\noexpand\csname\HyRef@name name\endcsname
           }%
           \noexpand~%
         }%
       }%
     }{%
       \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
         \noexpand\MyAutoefPhrasecolorGroup{%
           \expandafter\noexpand
           \csname\HyRef@name autorefname\endcsname
         }%
         \noexpand~%
       }%
     }%
   }{%
     \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
       \noexpand\MyAutoefPhrasecolorGroup{%
         \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1name\endcsname
       }%
       \noexpand~%
     }%
   }%
 }{%
   \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
     \noexpand\MyAutoefPhrasecolorGroup{%
       \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1autorefname\endcsname
     }%
     \noexpand~%
   }%
 }%
}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    {\bfseries\verb|\autoref|-references with hyperlink:}

    Textcolor unchanged: Insert cross reference \autoref{figure}

    Textcolor sawitched to green: \textcolor{green}{Insert cross reference \autoref{figure}}

    {\bfseries\verb|\autoref*|-references without hyperlink:}

    Textcolor unchanged: Insert cross reference \autoref*{figure}

    Textcolor sawitched to green: \textcolor{green}{Insert cross reference \autoref*{figure}}

\begin{figure}%h!
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Validation procedure for LR model}\label{figure}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\autoref`-references with hyperlinks the phrase "Figure" occurs in the color of the surrounding text and is clickable like the number which occurs in the color denoted by hyperref's `linkcolor`-key.